# Solr 7 and ICUFoldingFilterFactory

Tags: solr

I see that `ICUFoldingFilterFactory` is not used by default on a new Solr core in Solr 7 (In Solr 4 it was used for `text` fields.) The result is that there is no default field type that indexes "José" as "Jose" and allows for searches without the accents.

I know I can manually re-add `ICUFoldingFilterFactory` from the `contrib` folder back into Solr 7 and declare a new field type to use it, but I am wondering if Solr 7 provides equivalent functionality to `ICUFoldingFilterFactory` by default and I am just not seeing it.

Is there a new default (without using `contrib`) way in Solr 7 to get the the folding functionality in Solr 7?

Comment: what's the problem with using jars that are coming with Solr package?

Comment: No problem per-se. I am just surprised that I have to reach out for these extra jars for what seems to be such a basic feature (folding) that, from what I understand, *used to work by default* without manually configuring these jar files. It makes me wonder if there is a new way to do the same thing in Solr 7 that I am not seeing.

Comment: Oh, it was working out of the box, just because default solrconfig.xml have jar directives there and contrib jars are part of the distribution of Solr

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.